# The entityManager.remove(class) is not working

Tags: java, jpa, servlets

I got this method under a public class named Utilidades:

```
  public void delete(TipoUsuario tipoUsuario) throws Exception {
        if (em != null && tipoUsuario != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("NO SON NULOS");
                // TipoUsuario p = em.find(TipoUsuario.class, tipoUsuario);
              em.getTransaction().begin();
//                Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM TipoUsuario t WHERE t.idTipoUsuario = :idTipoUsuario");
//                query.setParameter("idTipoUsuario", tipoUsuario.getIdTipoUsuario());
//                int rows = query.executeUpdate();

               // if (em.contains(tipoUsuario)) {
                  //  em.remove(tipoUsuario);
               // } else {
                    em.remove(em.merge(tipoUsuario));
               em.getTransaction().commit();
             //   }

            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                Logger.getLogger(Utilidades.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, enfe.getMessage(), enfe);
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } else {
              System.out.println("NULOS");
        }
    }
```

I am injecting this class in a servlet and using this delete method but is not deleting the row

```
 String st = request.getParameter("txtIdUsuario").trim();
if (!(st == null || "".equals(st))) {
                    idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(st);
                }
                tipoUsuario.setIdTipoUsuario(idUsuario);
out.println("<h2>Se selecionó botón " + idUsuario + " eliminar</h2> ");
                        utilidades.delete(tipoUsuario);
                        out.println("<h2>Se selecionó botón eliminar</h2> ");
```

Do you guys have an idea of how can i do in order to delete a row?

Comment: why `em.merge` ?

Comment: So you are sure the method is being called and there is no exception?

Comment: You merge some changes in and then (want to) delete them?! Makes no sense. What does your debugging tell you? like looking at the LOG of the JPA provider? SQL invoked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Usually, we fetch from db to make sure the entity exists. Like
   `FROM TipoUsuario WHERE NAME = :name;`

   ```
   Query query = em.createNativeQuery("FROM TipoUsuario WHERE NAME = :name;", TipoUsuario.class)
           .setParameter("name", name);

   TipoUsuario tipoUsuario = null;

   try
   {
       tipoUsuario = (TipoUsuario) query.getSingleResult();
   }
   catch ( Exception e )
   {
       return null;
   }
   ```

Make sure NAME is the primary key of table TipoUsuario.
If you have the id of TipoUsuario, you can fetch the entity by
`em.find(TipoUsuario.class, id)`;

2. Anyway, you get the result you want. Then you do

`em.remote(tipoUsuario);`

to remote it. That's it.

Your issue exists that you just set one value of an object of TipoUsuario, but it is not the same result in table.

So `em.merge(obj)` just inserts a new row in table. Then you remove the new row. So the old row still exists in table.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a good idea. This is what i did and it worked:

                em.getTransaction().begin();
                TipoUsuario user = em.find(TipoUsuario.class, tipoUsuario.getIdTipoUsuario());
                em.remove(user);
                em.getTransaction().commit();